# Cromogenism, Chromudgeonism?

Tags: vocabulary, errors

In one of the commentary tracks for Hellsing Ultimate OVA, English dub director Tallison Jaffe boasts using a few rare words now and then, so the fans have something to look for in their dictionaries. I couldn't find the word he was talking about, and in the context in doesn't really make much sense to me.

> —Growing old seems so awful.
>
> —Nonsense. *Cromogenism* is a traditional pleasure for English gentlemen.

The context implies this word is related to aging.

Comment: Well, there is [chromogenic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chromogenic), _producing colour_, from which one could form _chromogenism_, I suppose, but that doesn't sound like a traditional pleasure for English gentlemen to me (although I'm prepared to be corrected).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Nonsense! [curmudgeonism](http://eyeonanime.co.uk/2dvd_reviewpage.php?dvdreviewid=890) is a traditional pleasure for English gentlemen." - Walter

*curmudgeon*: see [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/curmudgeon)